# Kubernetes Deplyment containers name vs hostname

Tags: kubernetes

In a Deployment of Kubernetes, what is the difference between `spec.containers.name` and `spec.hostname`?

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: CONFIG_HOME
          value: /config
      image: my-image:1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
      name: name-a
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      ...
  hostname: name-b
```

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to please update the status of question if any of below answer resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Container name**

Container name it's just the **name** you are providing to identify it.

it is useful to debug the **POD** when **failing** or running **multiple** **containers** inside **single** **POD**.

Get logs of **specific** container

```
kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <container-name>
```

**Hostname**

Only **service** get the **DNS** name record mapping not POD so you can't call the specific POD over **DNS** name unless you are using **statefulset**.

```
hostname: busybox-2
subdomain: busybox-subdomain
```

**hostname** and **subdomain** you can use the give **DNS** mapping to POD. FQDN fully qualified domain name.

You will be able to request that **POD** over the

```
hostname.subdomain.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local
```

you can **curl** the `hostname.subdomain.namespace-name.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 0):

`name:` gives the name of a container in a multi-container setup.  It's required, even if your Pod only has a single container.  It's only used in some administrative commands like `kubectl logs` or `kubectl exec`.

`hostname:` sets what the container believes its own hostname is; it does not affect anything outside the pod.  It defaults to the Pod's name.  It is unusual to need to set this.  It is part of the Pod network environment, and therefore all containers have the same hostname.

The only place `hostname:` matters at all is with a couple of specific services that use it to set a path in storage.  Of note, RabbitMQ does this.  Even then, if you run RabbitMQ in a StatefulSet, then the Pods will have predictable names and therefore the automatic hostname will be predictable as well.  You pretty much never need to manually set `hostname:`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the difference between those two using the command `kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.containers.name` to know more about the name field and use the command `kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.hostname` to know about hostname field.